# Error establishing multiple connections to MQTT - Python

Tags: python, mqtt

I'm trying to execute in the console a python script which contains:

```
python RC-accSimulation.py &
python RC-gyrSimulation.py &
python RT-accSimulation.py &
python RT-gyrSimulation.py &
python LC-accSimulation.py &
python LC-gyrSimulation.py &
python LT-accSimulation.py &
python LT-gyrSimulation.py &
```

These .py files are quite identical (following an example):

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

raspberry_MQTT_ip = '192.168.1.201'

jsonData = "..."

#Sending to MQTT Server the jsonData
mqttClient = mqtt.Client()
mqttClient.connect(host=raspberry_MQTT_ip, port=1883)
mqttClient.publish("topic/sensorRTgyr",jsonData)
```

If I execute five or less .py file in the script everything works fine.
unfortunately if I try to execute every file is presented in the script the following error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/giordano/Dropbox/Andrea/tesi/sensorsScripts/simulatedsensors/RT-gyrSimulation.py", line 60, in <module>
    mqttClient = mqtt.Client()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 497, in
__init__
    self._sockpairR, self._sockpairW = _socketpair_compat()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 245, in
_socketpair_compat
    sock1.connect(("127.0.0.1", port))   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args) socket.error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
```

replicated for each one of the py file present in the script.
I'm quite confused because the error is showed just if more of 5 py file are executed together. I tried different combinations in order to find a specific faulty file but no one is guilty.

Comment: Any particular reason these have to be separate scripts and you can't just use the Paho Python multiple publish function to publish them all in one go from a single client?

Comment: Any information in the MQTT broker log files?

Comment: mosquito log:
> 1505321174: Socket error on client 3ed3b888-a0f8-4d73-9331-690bcda52a7b, disconnecting
> 1505321174: Socket error on client c0287046-cfc1-4050-834e-83b5a627534d, disconnecting

the mosquitto broker is installed on a RPi3 and I need to keep scripts separated.

Comment: I want to add that the error doesn't appear immediately but after some seconds(20) of correct execution